# Is there any method to create a windows executable from python script besides pyinstaller?

Tags: python, windows, keras, executable, librosa

I have to create an exe file from my python script. I use pyinstaller, but sometimes it does not create executables, e.g., when I use libraries like librosa or Keras. Is there some other way to create executables?

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question to ask why the executables are not created when you include those libraries

Comment: If you're getting an error while creating an executable while using the packages `librosa` or `keras`, please add it to the question. Also, as mentioned by @OneCricketeer, update the title of the question.